# React native disable "Bluetooth pairing request" popup when connecting with react-native ble manager

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Whenever i try to connect to the peripheral BLE device i get a popup on my app asking if user wants to connect to bluetooth. If i click "no" on the popup everything works fine. If i click yes it still works, but then it is connected like you would connect earphones in bluetooth manager. That seems like a waste of battery and it gets in the way of the functionality of the app.

The application still reads and starts notification on the peripheral when clicking "no" on the popup. The data is "connected" on some level, but not in the Bluetooth Classic way.

I was wondering if there is a way to not show this popup, or if shown to not connect the user to bluetooth classic and just keep the notify connection.

I am using react-native ble manager library for scanning, connecting, reading and starting notification on my peripheral BLE device.

Any solutions for this? Maybe something that can be bridged from swift if there is no available solution on react-native?

Comment: I am having same problem while connecting, have you found  the solution ?

Comment: I belive it has to do with the peripheral device itself. If the device is encoded there is not much we can do from code standpoint.